# Edit dictionary to be a valid json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that specified a layout for a map I am going to use in javascript. The only thing I need to do to make this dictionary a valid json is to convert the single ' to ".

I am new to java and json stuff but here is a snippet of what the dictionary loos like:

```
    {'State': '336', 'Variable': 'Median Household Income', 'Year': 
'2017'}, 'below': 'water', 'type': 'fill', 'color': 'rgba(187, 214, 235, 
255)', 'maxzoom': 13, 'opacity': 0.7}], 'bearing': 0, 'center': {'lat': 
45.51439913430827, 'lon': -122.76771709039427}, 'pitch': 0, 'zoom': 9, 
'style': 'streets'}, 'margin': {'l': 0, 'r': 0, 't': 0, 'b': 0}, 
'plot_bgcolor': '#202d56', 'paper_bgcolor': '#202d56'}
```

Comment: A `dict` is never JSON. A dict is a materialized data structure, *there are no quotes in it*, that is merely how it is represented when it is printed. On the other hand, JSON is a text-based serialization format. To *serialize* a Python data structure, like a `dict` into a valid JSON string, you can use the `json` module.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you can you provide an answer? I really just need to figure out a way of replacing  ' to ".

Comment: I linked a duplicate. use `import json` then either `json.dumps(my_dict)` to create a json `str` or `json.dump(my_dict, file_handle)` to dump to a file. Here's the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga json.dumps does not work and returns this:SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Morgan.Weiss\Documents\workspace\pa-web-app\app\routes.js:637:31)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:607:12)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. `json.dumps` **definitely works**, but you need to show exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks but I made a new question to address what I exactly need.